# configuring the .net adfs claims aware sample application

Tags: c#, asp.net, adfs

attempting to get the sampleapp (a claims aware web forms application) available from mircosoft https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/TNBlogsFS/prod.evol.blogs.technet.com/telligent.evolution.components.attachements/01/8598/00/00/03/64/54/88/SampApp%20and%20Rules.zip to run on our web server.

our adfs server is www.fedsvc3copa.beta.pa.gov 
 the sample app is hosted at application is https://costa.beta.pa.gov/
 our federation metadata is https://www.fedsvc3copa.beta.pa.gov/federationmetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml

unfortunately believe I have something/s incorrect in my web config and struggling to find it. when I browse to https://costa.beta.pa.gov/ I receive

> WIF10201: No valid key mapping found for securityToken:
>   'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityToken' and issuer:
>   'http://www.fedsvc3copa.beta.pa.gov/adfs/services/trust'. Description:
>   An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current
>   web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenValidationException:
>   WIF10201: No valid key mapping found for securityToken:
>   'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityToken' and issuer:
>   'http://www.fedsvc3copa.beta.pa.gov/adfs/services/trust'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [SecurityTokenValidationException: WIF10201: No valid key mapping
>   found for securityToken:
>   'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityToken' and issuer:
>   'http://www.fedsvc3copa.beta.pa.gov/adfs/services/trust'.]
>   System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SamlSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(SecurityToken
>   token) +1461
>   System.IdentityModel.Services.TokenReceiver.AuthenticateToken(SecurityToken
>   token, Boolean ensureBearerToken, String endpointUri) +135
>   System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.SignInWithResponseMessage(HttpRequestBase
>   request) +666
>   System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object
>   sender, EventArgs args) +467
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +139    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +195    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
>   step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +88
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.7.3163.0

I have included my web config below if anyone notices anything that is incorrect.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <section name="system.identityModel.services" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelServicesSection, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
  </configSections>
  <location path="FederationMetadata">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestValidationMode="4.5" />
    <machineKey decryptionKey="5D497CFB20EB5927CB3FC44F65DBD3C6D6C366ACFCF20DC5" validationKey="80546F84BEDD8B38A995CCDD44E01C1794861685E605ECBFB5A231EAA7EAD9A99977312362EBDD2B9727F9357AF9A161F97AD49DD6E34E7CFC22D572BD4B90FD" />
  </system.web>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ida:FederationMetadataLocation" value="https://www.fedsvc3copa.beta.pa.gov/federationmetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml" />
    <add key="ida:Issuer" value="https://www.fedsvc3copa.beta.pa.gov/adfs/ls/" />
    <add key="ida:ProviderSelection" value="productionSTS" />
    <add key="ida:EnforceIssuerValidation" value="false" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
      <add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration>
      <audienceUris>
        <add value="https://costa.beta.pa.gov/" />
      </audienceUris>
      <!--Commented by Identity and Access VS Package-->
      <!--<issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry"><authority name="http://sts.costa.beta.pa.gov/adfs/services/trust"><keys><add thumbprint="I put my thumbprint here" /></keys><validIssuers><add name="sts.contoso.com" /></validIssuers></authority></issuerNameRegistry>-->
      <!--certificationValidationMode set to "None" by the the Identity and Access Tool for Visual Studio. For development purposes.-->
      <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None" />
      <!--Commented by Identity and Access VS Package-->
      <!--<issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry"><authority name="http://sts.costa.beta.pa.gov/adfs/services/trust"><keys><add thumbprint="?I put my thumbprint here" /></keys><validIssuers><add name="sts.contoso.com" /></validIssuers></authority></issuerNameRegistry>-->
      <issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry">
        <authority name="https://www.fedsvc3copa.beta.pa.gov/adfs/services/trust">
          <keys>
            <add thumbprint="I put my thumbrint here " />
          </keys>
          <validIssuers>
            <add name="https://www.fedsvc3copa.beta.pa.gov/adfs/services/trust" />
          </validIssuers>
        </authority>
      </issuerNameRegistry>
      <securityTokenHandlers>
        <add type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Tokens.MachineKeySessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <remove type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </securityTokenHandlers>
    </identityConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel>
  <system.identityModel.services>
    <federationConfiguration>
      <cookieHandler requireSsl="true" />
      <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="https://www.fedsvc3copa.beta.pa.gov/adfs/ls/" realm="https://costa.beta.pa.gov/" requireHttps="true" />
    </federationConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel.services>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From memory, it's because that certificate that matches that thumbprint isn't in the certificate store - local computer.